# C++ function make array based on arguments

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make a function that accepts a string and an int and makes an array of that given string and that given int. Example, given string "myarray" and 5 should make an array `int myarray[5];` I use:

```
void function(string x, int y) {
    int x[y];
}
```

but that gives me `declaration of 'int x[y]' shadows a parameter`... Any tips?

Comment: rename e.g. your first parameter `string x` to something else? you can't have declarations with equal names in the same scope ..

Comment: `int x[y]` doesn't declare a variable named `myarray`. Anyway, if you need dynamically-named and dynamically-sized arrays, use an `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector>`.

Comment: I don't understand what your function is supposed to do. The way you described it is: it does nothing except it declares a local array (illegally btw). Tell us more about what you try to achieve.

Comment: Nor does it declare an array of `string`s, as you appear to want.

Comment: check this out: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: I think OP wants the *name* of the array to come from parameter `x` - not possible of course.

Comment: To name an array like this, you would need a much more complex construct... Likely a class exposing the array's functions, but with an additional `name` member. It appears you might be rather new to C++ (not trying to be mean!) - I advise you *strongly* against trying to do your code like this; there *will* be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

`declaration of`int x[y]`shadows a parameter` effectively means that you're "hiding" another variable.

How should the compiler differentiate between your string argument called `x` and the array called `x`? It doesn't! They both got the same name so there's no way to access the string anymore.

That said the size of an array in C++ must be known at compile time, which isn't the case in your code. Some compilers make it available as an extension but if you want to stay standards compliant you should use an vector.

```
void function(std::string x, int y) {
    std::vector<int> other_name(y);
}
```

---

If you want to have an association between some `key` and a `value` you might want to look into [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

```
void function(string x, int y) {
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> my_map;

    my_map[x] = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

This will create a map that'll associate your string `x` with the vector `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Answer (score 3):

You can only really do this kind of thing with a macro, e.g.

```
#define FUNCTION(x, y) \
    int x[y]

// ...

FUNCTION(myarray, 5);
```

This will then expand to:

```
int myarray[5];
```

as required.

However I don't recommend it - if you explain the *real* problem behind this then there is probably a much better solution (that doesn't involve macros).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot name a variable at runtime, having a string name of the array.

You can only have compile time name of variables, meaning all the variables names have to be defined in code.

If you really really want to have dynamic names, than you should have some kind of maps, storing a string, the name of the vector, and a vector.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `vector` than a C-style array.  It's better to use the C++ Std Lib functions than to roll your own.  Given both of these things, what you're trying to do makes no sense outside of any context.

Lack of context, here is what I'd do:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const std::string val = "Foo";
    constexpr size_t numVals = 5;
    std::vector <std::string> myVals (numVals, val);
    std::copy (myVals.begin(), myVals.end(), std::ostream_iterator <std::string> (std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is variable hiding. You are hiding the parameter "x" by declaring a local variable "x". When the variable x is used the compiler only knows to use the local variable x which is an array and not the string x as passed.

If the nature of the string you are passing is supposed to be the variable name, this is not the syntax you were looking for and, in fact, doesn't exist. Variable names in C and C++ are declared during compile time, not run time. It can be difficult, if not impossible, to find out the name of a variable at run time.

That being said, there really is no reason to care what the function calls it's local array. It can be foo for all you care. It seems you are more concerned about creating a sized array using a function call. Something like the built in new.

```
int* x; // a pointer to an integer.
x = new int[10]; // x now points to an array of 10 ints and can be used as an array
// do stuff with x[] array here
delete[] x; // free up memory
```

If this is not the concept you were looking for, then your question is beyond me until you provide more feedback.